# How to handle Exception for bulk update in trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, error-messages, bulk-api

I have one Object for which we are doing bulk data update from Mulesoft, there is nothing which we are doing in salesforce for the same.
Now due to some validation, few records are getting failed. I need to handle those failed record and update one custom field Failed_Record_Reason__c with some value like 'Validation Failed'

I'm trying to do the same using trigger, but not sure how I'll get the failed record with the reason for their failure. As I'm not doing any DML operation in trigger

Comment: Are you using validation rules for validation or your trigger is validating incoming records??

Comment: I'm using validation rules for validation, nothing in trigger

Answer (score 2):

Errors that are caused by validation rules can't be caught in a trigger, since it's an API call. You would need to configure something within Mulesoft to do this, assuming it has the capability to do so.

Comment: I believe the same applies when we do update using data loader

Comment: @salesforceDeveloper Correct, any API call, regardless of source, needs to log the errors if you want to get the data. The Data Loader provides an "errorXXXXX.csv" that includes those errors, which you could actually use to log those errors into a separate object.